# I want to know if the firebase rules are writable or not from the client side

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm modifying it by practicing the firebase quick start program.

[[FriendlyChat]](https://github.com/firebase/codelab-%20friendlychat-android)

I have rewritten the rules and data this way.

Data

```
{"admin-users" : 
 {
      "my-uid" : true
 },
 "messages" : 
 {
       "-ABCD" : {
         "name" : "Mary",
         "text" : "Hi"
  },
  "-K2ib4H77rj0LYewF7dP" : {
         "name" : "anonymous",
         "text" : "Hello"
  },
  "-K2ib5JHRbbL0NrztUfO" : {
         "name" : "anonymous",
         "text" : "how are you"
  }
 }
}
```

Rules

```
{
   "rules": { ".read": "auth !
      ".read": "auth ! = null",
      ".write": "root.child('admin-users').child( auth.uid).exists()",
   }
}
```

I've succeeded in disabling all but "my-uid", but I've been able to get the I couldn't figure out how to reference it, so I got a text box and a "SEND" button, etc. You will be left in the dust.
Is there a way to reference it from the client side? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Self-resolved.Thank you.
I have added the following source code on line 29 of MainActivity.java

```
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    ValueEventListener vel;

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("/admin-users");

    vel = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            boolean approval=false;
            mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
            mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
            mAddMessageImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addMessageImageView);
            mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
            {

if(!mFirebaseUser.getUid().toString().equals(dataSnapshot.getKey()))continue;

                approval=true;
                break;
            }
            if(approval)
            {
                mMessageEditText.setEnabled(true);
                mMessageEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSendButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAddMessageImageView.setEnabled(true);
                mAddMessageImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                mMessageEditText.setEnabled(false);
                mAddMessageImageView.setEnabled(false);
                mMessageEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mSendButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mAddMessageImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(vel);
```